# Use DevTools protocol to open new tab in window

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, puppeteer

I am using puppeteer to launch a new Chrome browser window:

```
const util = require('util');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {

  const b = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    devtools: true, // open DevTools when window launches
    args: ['--remote-debugging-port=9222']
  });

  console.log('browser:', util.inspect(b));

  const c = await puppeteer.connect({
    browserWSEndpoint:   b._connection._url,   //`ws://${host}:${port}/devtools/browser/<id>`,
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: false
  });

  console.log('connection =>', c);

})();
```

my question is - how can I use the websocket connection `c`, to send DevTools protocol messages to the browser window? I'd like to open a new tab, and do some other actions. Anybody know how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haven't tested it but reading from the documentation you could do something like this:

```
const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();
await client.send('Target.createTarget', {'https://stackoverflow.com'});
```

You can find the:

- docs for **CPDSession** [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-cdpsession)
- docs for **Chrome Dev Tools Protocol** [here](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Target#method-createTarget).